# Using Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$−4(\frac{dy}{dt}) − y = 0, y(0) = −8$

I need to use $Y$ for Laplace transform of $y$.

$() = Y{0}$

So $Y = −\frac{8}{(s−\frac{1}{4})}$ and $y(t) = −8e^{−\frac{t}{4}}$

I tried $sY+8+(\frac{1}{4})Y=Y{0}$ but it says I am incorrect.

Comment: Exact duplicate by the OP: [Laplace Transform of the IVP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4313677)

Comment: You should fix your original question (linked in the above comment) if you want an answer. Don't just repost the exact question.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I did not see anything wrong with my question posted. No one commented on what was wrong. I just was looking for another set of eyes to see what I had done wrong.

Comment: Have you tried solving the diff eq by more traditional methods?  i.e. it is a separable diff eq.  What result do you get that way and how does it compare with your answer using the Laplace transform?